# Using a completion handler in another class/extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class, `LocationViewController`, which needs to implement a `TableView`. I have a function `getParsedTestingLocation()` which uses a completion handler from another function to get some data.

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func getParsedTestingLocations(completion: @escaping ([TestingLocation]?, Error?) -> (Void)) {
        getTestingLocationsJSON(completion: { testLocationsJSON, error in
            if let testLocationsJSON = testLocationsJSON {
                let testLocationsData = Data(testLocationsJSON.utf8)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let testLocations = try decoder.decode([TestingLocation].self, from: testLocationsData)
                    completion(testLocations, nil)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I want to use the value `testLocations` within `getParsedTestingLocations()` in an external extension in this file. Here are the extensions I have:

```
extension LocationViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("you tapped me!")
    }
}

extension LocationViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "empty cell"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Within all 3 `tableView()` functions I want to get the values stored in `testLocations` in the completion handler in these functions. How could I do this?

Comment: Where are you calling `getParsedTestingLocations`? In which class?

Comment: Where is `getParsedTestingLocations` called? Basically you have to add a data source array, assign the received data, adjust the dataSource methods and call `reloadData()`. And an *external extension* is practically a part of the class.

Comment: @Rob I haven't called it yet, but the return value from the completion handler needs to be used in all 3 `tableView()` functions, so I did not want to repeatedly call the handler if I can call it once and use the return value as needed. Currently, each of the `tableView()` functions are just within an extension of `LocationViewController`, which are defined outside of the class. Is there a way to get the completion handler's return value to the extensions even though they are technically outside of the class?

Comment: @vadian `getParsedTestingLocations()` is not called yet as I didn't know the best way to retrieve its value as I need to use it within each of the 3 `tableView()` functions. Like you said, I think I do need some array to receive the data, but I am unsure how to do this with the completion handler within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need a completion handler. Reload the table view inside the completion closure of the API call

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var locationData = [TestingLocation]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getParsedTestingLocations()
    }

    func getParsedTestingLocations() {
        getTestingLocationsJSON(completion: { testLocationsJSON, error in
            if let testLocationsJSON = testLocationsJSON {
                let testLocationsData = Data(testLocationsJSON.utf8)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    self.locationData = try decoder.decode([TestingLocation].self, from: testLocationsData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

extension LocationViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locationData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let location = locationData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = location.whatEverStringYouWantToDisplay
        return cell
    }

}
```

Replace `whatEverStringYouWantToDisplay` with the real struct member name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `completionHandler` in `getParsedTestingLocations` in this case as the function already calls a function which has completionHandler. Just use a variable

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var locationArr = [TestingLocation]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getParsedTestingLocations()
    }

    func getParsedTestingLocations() {
        getTestingLocationsJSON(completion: { testLocationsJSON, error in
            if let testLocationsJSON = testLocationsJSON {
                let testLocationsData = Data(testLocationsJSON.utf8)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let testLocations = try decoder.decode([TestingLocation].self, from: testLocationsData)
                    self.locationArr = testLocations
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch let error {
                   //Show Alert
                }
            }
        })
    }
    }

    extension LocationViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

             func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return locationArr.count
  }
                
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
     cell.textLabel?.text = locationArr[indexPath.row].variable
                    return cell
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                print("you tapped me! \(locationArr[indexPath.row])")
            }
}
```